# Error while solving the differential equation $x^3 + y + 2xy' = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> I have a differential equation such that $x^3 + y + 2xy' = 0$

- According to my textbook the solution should look like this:

$ y' - \frac {y}{2x} = \frac {x^2}{2} = 0$  $\;$ (solving the homogenous system)

$\int \frac {dy}{y} = \int \frac {dx}{2x}$  ,

but I am very confused why the result of that homogenous part look like this: $y = c \sqrt {\vert x \vert}$.  Did I miss something?

- My own result is $y = 2xc$

Comment: Where do we begin ? ... do either of these solutions actually satisfy the original equation ? (Do the calculation) ... can the original equation be manipulated to what the book suggests ? ... Is the equation homogenous or linear ?

Comment: Could you please check again all the signs, the original equation at this moment is not the same as the first transformed equation. $$ x^3+y+2xy'=0$$ transforms to $$y'+\frac{y}{2x}=-\frac{x^2}2.$$

Comment: While $$x^3-y+2xy'=0$$ indeed transforms to $$y'-\frac{y}{2x}=-\frac{x^2}2$$ leading to the reported signs and powers in the textbook solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation

$$ y' - \frac{y}{2x} = x^2/2 $$

is equivalent to (introduce an integrating factor)

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \frac{y}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{x^2}{2\sqrt{x} } = \frac{x^{3/2}}{2}$$

which can be easily integrated.

Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: That's very true @LutzL, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So you integrate to get
$$ \log{y} = \frac{1}{2}\log{x}+k $$
Applying the exponential function to both sides gives
$$ e^{\log{y}} = e^{(1/2)\log{x}+k} = e^k e^{(1/2)\log{x}}, $$
and $e^{a\log{x}} = x^a$ for any $a$. Remember the exponential turns addition into multiplication, and constants don't come out of it ($e^{2x} \neq 2e^{x}$, for example).

But most importantly, remember that you can check the solution of a differential equation by substituting back in: your result does not satisfy the differential equation, so it can't work!